# How can I label the x-axis of my tikz plot with variables?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I am struggling to label the x-axis with my desired points 0, a, b respectively. I want `0` to sit just below the origin, `a` to sit below where the white rectangle ends and `b` to sit below where the grey rectangle ends. Also `--` the y-axis. Where the white rectangle ends on the y axis I was looking to include the point `f(a)` and where the grey rectangle ends along the y-axis I wanted `f(b)`. I do not know where to start to include this; any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code: [I do not know how to showcase the image itself.]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=gray, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (4,4) ; 

\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (2,2) ;

\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[anchor = north west]{x-axis};

\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[anchor= north east]{y-axis} ;

\draw[thick, black] (2,2) .. controls (0,4) and (4,0) .. (4,4) ;
\end{center}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={a=2;b=4;}] 
 \filldraw[fill=gray, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (b,b) ;
 \filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (a,a) ;
 \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[anchor = north west]{$x$ axis};
 \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[anchor= north east]{$y$ axis} ;
 \draw[thick, black] (2,2) .. controls (0,4) and (4,0) .. (4,4) ; 
 \path[nodes={text height=1.2em}] (0,0) node[below]{$0$}
 (a,0) node[below]{$a$} (b,0) node[below]{$b$}
 (0,a) node[left]{$f(a)$} (0,b) node[left]{$f(b)$} ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Love the name!